# using MySQL, what is the most efficient way to find avg(data) per period of time

Tags: mysql, sql

I using MySQL to store data from environmental sensors every 10 - 15 seconds. I want to find the max, min and average for every hour. The problem I'm having is the time is stored as Epoch time, (seconds since 1970, not mS). 
Would I be better to create a new column with the date stamp in `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS` format?

Comment: You can convert that into a date https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple enough to do with arithmetic:

```
select floor(epoch / (60*60)), min(x) max(x), avg(x)
from t
group by floor(epoch / (60*60));
```

You can convert this back using `unix_timestamp()`:

```
select unix_timestamp(min(epoch), '%Y-%m-%d %H'), min(x) max(x), avg(x)
from t
group by floor(epoch / (60*60));
```